# How do i remove blank lines from code filled list

Tags: excel-formula

I have a problem and have modified “jlore” code of =if(d3 = "PS588", c3, "")
 which works, but is there a way to populate so I don't get blank lines? My task is to generate an Excel HV switching program on one sheet then on the next an isolation list. I am attempting to auto populate the Isolation list with the code =IF(HVSP!H30 = "APPLY ISOL LOCK & TAG", HVSP!E30, "").
However as stated if the "APPLY ISOL LOCK &TAG" isn't in the cell my isolation list creates a blank line.
Regards

Steve Mack

Comment: Can you post screenshot to your question to better understand your issue?

Answer (score 1):

If i have understood your question correctly, you are getting a blank cell because of the `,"")` at the end.  If you change this to `,"DON'T APPLY ISOL LOCK & TAG")` or wording of your choice you will not get a blank cell.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Thanks for answering, Not quite what I'm after, I believe the issue is because I populate the data line by line, whenever the source line is false I get a blank. What I need is a way of collating the true values into a collective list. I assume I will need a second data sheet to achieve this. Thanks

Comment: Do you have any more information, so i can see what you are trying to do?

Comment: OK so on the first page of my workbook I have the HV switching program, which will go something like this,rack out breaker, second line, confirm racked out, third line, apply isol lock and tag. this goes on until program end (sometimes 200 steps) on the second page I have the data for all the drop down boxes on the first page. On the third page I have an isolation list of all the points to be locked and tagged (Maybe 3-20 points) however when I import from the first page I have blank lines whenever the text does not read "APPLY ISOL LOCK &TAG". I need a way to eliminate the blank lines

Comment: I have tried Array formulas like=INDEX($B$1:$B$10, SMALL(IF(ISBLANK($B$1:$B$10), "", ROW($B$1:$B$10)-MIN(ROW($B$1:$B$10))+1), ROW(A8))) but it appears because my list is filled due to formula it still pics up the blanks.

Comment: Found the answer thanks it is =IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$15,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$15<>"",ROW($A$1:$A$15),999),ROW(1:1))),"") This works a treat but as I said before it necessitates the use of an intermediate page but I just hide that page. Thanks

Comment: You could add something like this to your code which would delete blank rows based on a blank cell. `Columns("put a column letter here").SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow.Delete`